# 'sub or function not defined'

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with `Sub or Function not defined` error with my program below. could anyone help me solve this?

**Main Macro:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    EraseWorkSheetKeepRow1 ("FilteredItems")
     Sheets("SalesData").Select
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    For i = 2 To k
        Sheets("SalesData").Select
        If Val(Cells(i, 3)) > Val(TextBox1.Text) Then
          Call Copy1row("SalesData", i, "FilteredItems")
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

**Sub Routine1 (EraseWorkSheetKeepRow1):**

```
Sub EraseWorkSheetKeepRow1(sheetname As String)
'
' EraseWorkSheetKeepRow1 Macro
' Erase all rows except row 1 for worksheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CustomerInfo).Select
    Dim k As Integer
    k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    Range("A2:C" & k).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

**Sub Routine2 (Copy1row):**

```
Sub Copy1row(FromSheet As String, rowno As Integer, ToSheet As String)
'
' Copy1row Macro
    Sheets(CustomerInfo).Select
    Rows(rowno & ":" & rowno).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(ToSheet).Select
    Dim k As Integer
    k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    Rows(k & ":" & k).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
        Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, _
        Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: it works for me. Can you provide your test workbook? (i.e. uisng https://www.dropbox.com) Maybe I could help you..

Comment: sorry but im not so familiar with dropbox. could you tell me how i could share it with dropbox?

Comment: I am not so sure but I think this line `EraseWorkSheetKeepRow1 ("FilteredItems")` will cause you problem. use this instead `Call EraseWorkSheetKeepRow1 ("FilteredItems")` like what you did in your other sub routine. or you can write it like this `EraseWorkSheetKeepRow1 "FilteredItems"`.

Answer (score 0):

this error usually has nothing to do with the code itself. Please check that the sub name is not the same as the module name and that you haven't used the same name in another sub as this can cause the definition error.